# nvcc compiler setup Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I successfully installed the nvidia driver and toolkit for cuda 5 (but not the samples) on a 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 box. The samples failed to install even though I previously ran

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
```

I can't seem to find nvcc. I ran

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

`nvcc -v` reports that the compiler is not found:

```
nvcc -V No command 'nvcc' found, did you mean:
 Command 'nvlc' from package 'vlc-nox' (universe)
nvcc: command not found
```

The getting started guide hasn't been of much help [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html).

What's going on here? Do I need to install the gpu computing sdk samples to get nvcc?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you installed `nvcc` but it's not in the [executable path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

The libraries are located in `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib` and `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/lib64`, so the executables are probably located in `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin`. Check in that directory, to see if there is a file called `nvcc`. If so, add `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin` to [your `PATH` environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path).

If `nvcc` is not located there, search the entire `/usr/local/cuda-5.0` directory. One way to do that is to run the command:

```
find /usr/local/cuda-5.0 -name nvcc
```

Once you find it, you can add the directory that contains it to your `PATH` variable, or you can make a symbolic link to it in a directory that's in your `PATH`, or you can invoke it by its full path name (e.g., `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/someplace/nvcc`).

Answer (score 3):

In my build (Ubuntu Server 13.10), `nvcc` ended up in /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit (in the 'bin' directory) - adding a symlink to there from /usr/local/cuda fixed up all of my CUDA problems.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit /usr/local/cuda
```

But YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

// , Follow the instructions outlined here:

http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda7.0-ubuntu

NVCC is part of the CUDA Toolkit.

I recommend installing the CUDA Toolkit directly from NVIDIA's site for such things:

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?sid=899051

Visit the above link, select the Linux x86 tab, and pick the .deb file for your distribution.

Like Eliah Kagan said, you'll find it in the default installation directory for the Toolkit files.

e.g., if you had CUDA 7.0 one would search in the /usr/local/cuda-7.0 directory:

```
find /usr/local/cuda-7.0 -name nvcc
```

The above command should generate output like `/usr/local/cuda-7.0/bin/nvcc`

If that doesn't work, try a more general search, like

```
find /usr/local -name nvcc
```

...or check where that version installed itself.

If one installs a different version, obviously the directory where it flings its files will vary accordingly.

Also, make sure that the shell gets nvcc and other runnables in its executable path by adding the following in the .bashrc file of your home folder.

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-7.0 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64 

PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH} 
export PATH
```

The above will allow you to run `make` for CUDA projects without errors about the meaninglessness of `nvcc`.

Comment: This worked for me on a P2 AWS instance running ubuntu