# nvcc not found, but only when using sudo

Tags: nvidia, bash, sudo, bashrc, cuda

I can't get ANYTHING working on linux. I'm [trying to compile CudaMiner](https://litecointalk.org/index.php?topic=3231.0). Output of `sudo make`:

```
ypt-jane.o `test -f 'scrypt-jane.cpp' || echo './'`scrypt-jane.cpp
mv -f .deps/cudaminer-scrypt-jane.Tpo .deps/cudaminer-scrypt-jane.Po
nvcc -g -O2 -Xptxas "-abi=no -v" -arch=compute_10 --maxrregcount=64 --ptxas-options=-v -I./compat/jansson -o salsa_kernel.o -c salsa_kernel.cu
/bin/bash: nvcc: command not found
make[2]: *** [salsa_kernel.o] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/progs/CudaMiner'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/progs/CudaMiner'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So, kind of interesting. Output of `nvcc`:

```
nvcc fatal   : No input files specified; use option --help for more information
```

Whereas the output of `sudo nvcc`:

```
sudo: nvcc: command not found
```

I have identical exports listed in `~/.bashrc` AND `/etc/bash.bashrc`. (Nvcc is located in: `/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/nvcc`)

I also tried changing the current path, to no avail:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/nvcc
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So apparently, `nvcc` is not on the `PATH` when you run it with `sudo`. You can confirm this with:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```

The easiest solution is to call `sudo` with the absolute path of `nvcc`:

```
sudo $(which nvcc)
```

When running commands without absolute path like `nvcc`, `sudo` uses the value of the `secure_path` configuration in `/etc/sudoers` as the `PATH`, for example in my system:

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

So even if you set `PATH` in one of the startup files that the shell normally sources, it won't work. If you want to make `sudo nvcc` work temporarily, just to get your build working, I think you have two options:

- Edit the installer script and change the lines with `sudo nvcc` to `sudo /path/to/nvcc`
- Create a symlink to `nvcc` in one of the directories listed in `secure_path`, like this: `sudo ln -s /path/to/nvcc /sbin/nvcc`

**UPDATE**

If you have a hard time finding the path of `nvcc`, you can try these commands, in this order (they get slower and slower), until you find a match:

```
which nvcc
find /usr/local/cuda-5.0 -name nvcc
find /usr/local/ -name nvcc
find /opt -name nvcc
find / -name nvcc
```

Comment: Is there a way I can include /usr/local/cuda-5.0/bin/ just for the current session in the terminal such that when time comes and make script calls upon it it will find it? I don't think I'll ever need it again.

Comment: @dsp_099 yup, see my updated answer

Comment: I tried the symlink way with the command listed and that didn't work, however editing the installer script worked great. Might also want to include the link to http://askubuntu.com/questions/231503/nvcc-compiler-setup-ubuntu-12-04 so people who are noobs(like myself) can let this be a one stop shop

Comment: Thanks @JamesTobin! I'm happy to add links that improve the answer, but I don't see the added value in the link you posted. Can you explain?

Comment: For those people who wouldn't know how to find where their nvcc is located. Its hard to add it to the path if you don't know where it is

Comment: @JamesTobin I see, I added a note about that.

Comment: @janos very nice, hopefully others will find it useful as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-E` option of `sudo` to preserve your user environment. From the man page:

```
 -E, --preserve-env
             Indicates to the security policy that the user wishesto preserve their existing environment
             variables.  The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to
             preserve the environment.
```

You can test this with:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```

and then

```
sudo nvcc
```

Answer (score -1):

The cause might be a read-only folder. In my case the 'Make' file that calls nvcc was in a read-only folder. Changing the folder permission settings solved my problem.